# Find implicit solution for ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE

$$ [y(x)]^2cos(x)+y(x)f(x)y'(x)=0 $$

So first I want to find all functions for $f(x)$ so that the Differential equation is exact.

Basically following must be true...

$a(x,y) := y(x)cos(x) \, dx =f(x)\, dy=:b(x,y)$

Now I differentiate $a(x,y)$ for $dy$ and $b(x,y)$ for $dx$

Then...

$a_y = cos(x)y'(x)$ and $b_x=f'(x)$

$$cos(x)y'(x) = f'(x)$$

$$ \int cos(x)dy = \int f'(x) dx$$

$$ cos(x)y(x) + C = f(x) $$

Then I need to find "the implicit solution of the ODE for these functions f(x)". But what exactly does that mean?

Just plug in $f(x)$ in the original equation leave it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is $y^2\cos x dx + y f(x) dy =0$. It is exact if
$2y\cos x = yf'(x)$. Then, $f'(x)=2\cos x$ and $f(x) = 2\sin x+c$.